# IIS 7 Root Path is not working anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.5

I'm using asp.net 4.5. I created an application "MySite" in IIS as I did many times before but the path is different than before.

I have an img tag like this on my code

```
 <img src="/images/apple.jpg" />


IIS 7.5         : http://localhost/images/apple.jpg
IIS Express     : http://localhost:10753/images/apple.jpg
Web Server      : http://examplesite.com/images/apple.jpg
```

What I want :

```
        http://localhost/MySite/images/apple.jpg
```

What I get :

```
        http://localhost/images/apple.jpg
```

What can I do to make the default root path as "mysite" in IIS 7.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Virtual Directory under the root of your website in IIS so that the app you've created is under the directory MySite.

If you have a Default website setup in IIS right click on it and select 'Add Application' and go from there.

I think though that you're going to get more issues, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve and why you want to do it. Also your terminology 'default root path' is wrong, `http://localhost/` is always the root.

Comment: I was doing it the same way for a very long time. Creating a virtual directory or mostly add application under the "Default Web Site" in IIS. But now when I want to reach the root path of my web site, I can't. Even the tilde sign doesn't work. I think something changed in IIS7 Application Pool but I'm not sure what it is. I  change Asp.net 4.0 Integrated to Asp.net 4.0 Classic but that doesn't help either.